# Hiding loader after jquery formdata completed for each file

Tags: php, jquery, loader

I'm making a file uploader. Here is my code which is posting files to the php file in a for loop.
I want to hide loaders for each div after related image uploaded successfully. But with this code all loaders are being removed. There is no problem to append images to the div but I can't mind how should i use loader show/hide in this situation.

Maybe my codes are not good enough. I need some advices about it.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
                var file = this.files[i];
                var fd = new FormData();

                fd.append("th_photo", file);

                var loader = '<div class="content-loader">'+
                '<svg class="loader-circular" viewBox="25 25 50 50">'+
                '<circle class="loader-path" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>'+
                '</svg>'+
                '</div>';

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache: false,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    url: '../assets/_php/actions.php',
                    data: fd,
                    beforeSend:function(data){
                        $('.up_preview').append(
                            '<div class="uploaded_photo_loader" id="tmp_'+i+'">'
                            +loader+'</div>');
                    },
                    success:function(data){
                        $('.up_preview').append(
                            '<div class="uploaded_photo_grid">'+
                            '<img class="previewItem" src="'+data.fcontent+'">'+
                            '</img></div>');


                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: Still i couldn't find a solution to remove loaders after each formdata files uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can set and ID for each loader (you could use the `for` var to create the ID)
Then in the success function of the AJAX Request, you could use jQuery to hide the loader.

This is what I mean:

```
for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
var file = this.files[i];
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("th_photo", file);

console.log("========= START ==========");

var loaderName = 'loader_n' + i + '"';
console.log("-> " + loaderName);

var loader = '<div id="' + loaderName + ' class="content-loader">'+
            '<svg class="loader-circular" viewBox="25 25 50 50">'+
            '<circle class="loader-path" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>'+
            '</svg>'+
            '</div>';
console.log("-> " + loader);

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    url: '../assets/_php/actions.php',
    data: fd,
    beforeSend:function(data){
    $('.up_preview').append(
        '<div class="uploaded_photo_loader" id="tmp_'+i+'">'
         +loader+'</div>');
    },
    success:function(data){
        $('.up_preview').append(
            '<div class="uploaded_photo_grid">'+
            '<img class="previewItem" src="'+data.fcontent+'">'+
            '</img></div>');
        var newName = '"#' + loaderName; //Get the div ID and using it on jQuery
        console.log("-> " + newName);
        $(newName).hide();

                }
            });
        }
     }
```

**EDIT: Fixed some issues.**

Comment: Thank you for your response. In your code edited, i solved some mistakes but at this point just one loader is hiding. I think i need one more for loop to catch each id of loader.

Comment: Weird, if my logic is correct, this code will pick up a different ID every time it iterates... I'll try to get you a better solution

Comment: I'm stuck. Thank you very much !

Comment: Alright, I edited the code above, can you run it, check the console, and tell me what it says? Please

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/HO81Xtk.jpg here is the console result. "i" value returns as the last id of loader. The problem is here from the beginning ^_^ i think that it should be return as array.

Comment: I tried to replicate a situation like yours with the same code and it worked, so I don't know why it isn't working with you... I'm out of ideas, sorry!

Comment: Okay thank you again. I'll work on it. Maybe there is another way to show/hide loader after formdata success:function.